# Why do I have to double click to activate jquery function?

Tags: jquery, css

Good evening,

I am having trouble trying to work out why I have to click the test button twice to activate the jquery function where a side navigation bar will slide in from the left. I wanted to do this by targeting the width css class to make it 'grow'.

Then when I click the close button it returns to normal.

Here is the code shown below I hope there is enough there to go on forgive me I am fairly new to this:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="test">Click me</a>

<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="closebtn"><a href="">Close me</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #ee81e0;
}

.test {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #d4127e;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").click(function(){
        $(".sidenav").css('width', '350px');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".closebtn").click(function(){
        $(".sidenav").css('width', '0px');
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, since they aren't actually links, you could use buttons instead so you don't have to use `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the default behavior of the `a` tag if you want to stay on the same page and just toggle the nav. By default, the browser will try to follow the `a` tag when you click on it. Since your `href` attribute is empty, that will just try to go to the current page, or effectively reload the page. You can keep the browser from trying to follow the link by passing the `e` event to your click  handler function, and calling `e.preventDefault()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function(e) {
    $(".sidenav").css('width', '350px');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".closebtn").click(function() {
    $(".sidenav").css('width', '0px');
  });
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: #ee81e0;
}

.test {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #d4127e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="test">Click me</a>

<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="closebtn"><a href="">Close me</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndyLyell awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 2 `.ready()` functions. Wrap it all in 1.

Also, use `event.preventDefault();` so that the event does not bubble further.

Read up: [`event.preventDefault()` | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

**Working code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function(event) {
    $(".sidenav").css('width', '350px');
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $(".closebtn").click(function() {
    $(".sidenav").css('width', '0px');
  });
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #ee81e0;
}
.test {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d4127e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="test">Click me</a>

<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="closebtn"><a href="">Close me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have wrapped the functions into one :)